# Typescript syntax related

Tags: node.js, typescript, syntax

I am starting to develop applications using typescript. I had come across a code snippet where I couldn't understand the line marked within ** <> **. Anybody please throw some light.

```
export const applyRoutes = (routes: Route[], router: Router) => {
  for (const route of routes) {
    const { method, path, handler } = route;
    **(router as any)[method](path, handler);**
  }
};
```

Regards,
Karthikeyan R

Comment: At runtime it's the same as `router[method](path, handler)`; do you need help understanding that syntax?  Or is it just the `(router as any)` part?

Comment: It consists of three constructs: `(something as any)`, `something[key]`, and `something(arg1, arg2)`, do you understand them separately?

Answer (score 1):

`(router as any)` tells typescript that regardless of what it thinks the types are, it should treat `router` as having type `any`. In other words, it turns off type checking.

`router[method](path, handler)` means "access the `method` property on `router`, then call it passing in `path` and `handler`".